# Permanently install a non App Store app on an iPad - without expiration

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

Is it possible to permanently install a non App Store app on an iPad, without worrying about whether provisioning might expire?

I'm creating a 1 of a kind art piece with a one-off iOS app that accompanies the piece and since it's 1 of a kind, I don't think it's proper to be on the App Store.

Comment: Have you asked Apple?

Comment: how??????????????

Comment: Using your mouth to speak or your hands to type i suppose

Comment: i mean which channel? have tried app support - they keep sending default responses that are copypasta from policy

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible. All current methods of distribution, including those available through the ordinary App Store developer program and the Enterprise Developer program, have expiration dates.

Another answer mention Enterprise distribution as the solution - but it is not. The provisioning profile expires after 1 year, and the certificate itself after 3 years. So you would have to renew it in order to have the app working for many years.